# Restoring a database using Postgres data files instead of .sql files

Tags: postgresql, migration

I backed up my Ubuntu 14.04 system using rsync to a USB stick, but apparently it wasn't formatted for booting. The original disk has been erased and I put a fresh install of Ubuntu on it. In migrating my data I forgot to dump one of my postgres databases to SQL, and I need to migrate it to my new install of Ubuntu.

I'm considering formatting a bootable disk and then attempting to rsync my old system to that for disk so I can boot and dump my database to SQL. But that's a discussion for a different forum.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the data files from my old system to restore my database (i.e. copy `/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main`) from my old install to my new install? Has anyone ever done this? I did try just copying the data file but it caused Postgres to break beyond repair. I had to delete it entirely and reinstall.

I know it's possible with MySQL, but I'm less familiar with Postgres.

Thanks!

Comment: You can copy the whole data directory and it'll work fine. In Ubuntu you must also copy `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` from `/etc/postgresql`, since they're stored outside the PostgreSQL data directory. Please be more specific about "break beyond repair".

Answer (score 2):

Rsync is a supported backup method for postgresql.
However it has [some caveats that you need to be aware of](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-file.html). Namely the database should be offline when the sync is done.

So if your database was offline when you synced, you could restore it jsut fine.